# How to read/access attachment from email in Lightning Component on Lightning for Outlook?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Currently as per Salesforce document we can access the email body using "messageBody" attribute. Salesforce link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_email_app_pane.htm

But how can we access the attachment related to email? Salesforce do not give any function or parameters to access the attachment anywhere in document. If someone worked on it then please help me on this.

Basically I need to replicate the "standard relate email" functionality from Lightning for Outlook and perform some customization on it.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question a few weeks back to the Product Manager at the Lightning Now Tour, and unfortunately this is not yet possible.

So far you just have access to the attributes described in the link you gave.

I've just created an idea for that:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VrFQAU